# Jquery submitting multipage page form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I am trying to put together a quiz system and I am using this [jQuery multi page form plugin](http://thecodemine.org/) () coupled with this [countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html). My goal is to setup a line of questions using the multi page form and in case the user does not finish in time have the countdown plugin submit the form automatically.

I tried to use the jQuery submit function but I only get the last answer. This is my countdown code:

> $('#countdown').countdown({until: +1800, format: 'MS', onExpiry:
>   forceFormSubmit});

And this is my submit part:

> ```
> > function forceFormSubmit(){     
> >     window.onbeforeunload = null;
> >     $('#quizForm').submit();  }
> ```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? any other way to submit this form?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question and thanks to a tip received from the creator of the multi page form plugin, all I had to do was to enable the input fields before I submit the form.